# programing pseudocode

Tags: python

I'm trying to make the game [KenKen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KenKen) in Python.

I need some help with the pseudocode. What data types required to store and process the game information as it progresses and completes?

Comment: And what have you done so far?

Comment: I love how this comment continues to get upvoted ;)

Comment: i just stared! just need some Pesudocode to know how to get started.

Comment: @Wayne: they should make community post it if no intended blocks were identified in the question.

Comment: @babikar: Have you got any ideas? Try throwing something out, so other SO users can discuss it. If your wrong it's ok, you'll be corrected. But if you think that people will just do this for you you're wrong.

Comment: You are far away from having Pseudocode, IMO.  How well have you defined exactly what you want to do?  For example, how many mock KenKen exercises have you tried?  How well have you researched how a KenKen game is made and what difficulty it has?  These are better starting questions than a "Show me the code, please" which you seem to be asking.

Comment: i just wanted a simple not detailed Pesudacode! damn! no need to talk like this!!

Comment: @babikar: we all want people to do our work for us.  If you can't describe -- in a simple summary -- what's going on, then we can't either.

Answer (score 3):

By the sound of your question, babikar, you assumedly have very little knowledge of game programming in any language? If so, I advise that you start by looking for tutorials and books to read about both game programming in Python, and in general - the theory is usually language independent. You cannot expect people here to just give you psuedo-code - that requires time and effort for something that they would get nothing from. Creating psuedo-code can be just as hard, if not harder than writing the actual code - you are basically asking us to create your game for you.

[I suggest this should be your first search.](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&source=hp&q=python+game+tutorials)

**EDIT:**

To expand slightly and meet your question about actual game psuedo-code more - what exactly do you want to make, in terms of a 'KenKen' game. Is it a KenKen solver - a program that you give a KenKen puzzle to and it gives you the answer - or a KenKen generator - one that creates a KenKen puzzle for you to solve (and probably has other features too)?

[Here is a post on a KenKen solver in Python](http://daveshields.wordpress.com/2009/02/28/kenken-solver-in-python/) - but if you are going to make one of these, I wouldn't read his code or it will just ruin the making for you.

Comment: +1: well said. i hope the user works on it on his own in the end...

Comment: i was trying to make a kenken game! and you just sent me the codes?!?!? and all u guys just say we dont give codes?!?!? crazy people!

Comment: @babikar We don't sit and write code for you - pseudo or otherwise. What I have linked there is a post where someone else has written their *own* code to solve KenKen puzzles, since you might find it useful to **refer** to when writing your own. Of course, that is only if you are making a solver - as it says in my post, that might not even be what you're wanting to do. I think you perhaps have underestimated the complexity of either a Kenken solver or generator - it is not a simple task, and begins not with the programming but with understanding how the game really works.

Comment: You fool! You just sent him the codes! Go to DEFCON 1 immediately!

Comment: wooow u guys!! so wat if he sent me the answer!! u guys r .....